What value to set for "coxfit" in "hr_plot" function in "finalfit" package to plot the outcome of multivariable cox proportional hazard mode?
I want to plot the hazard ratio of multivariable cox proportional hazard model but my r code is giving plot of univariable cox proportional hazard model
I wrote the following code but i think assigning value for coxfit was inappropriate.
Install.packages (“finalfit “)
hr_plot(
    KM_cox_HR_1_year,
    dependent_os,explanatory,
    factorlist = NULL,
    coxfit = coxphmulti(), remove_ref = TRUE,
    breaks = NULL,
    column_space = c(-0.5, 0, 0.5),
    dependent_label = "Survival",
    prefix = "",
    suffix = ": HR (95% CI, p-value)",
    table_text_size = 4,
    title_text_size = 13)


Welcome to SO. Please familiarise yourself with how to ask a good question and provide a minimal reproducible example to help us to reproduce the error and debug it.
I would also suggest adding more appropriate tags. These should include the programming language (I believe it's R here), as well as libraries if you want your question to be seen by the right experts.
